# Saving user configuration options

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating a winform application in .net 2 with c#. I need to be able to save user configuration data and I am considering using an XML file for this propose. What is the general feeling for saving user configuration data? I have read that it is not   in vogue  to write to the registry but rather to a file instead. Please write your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [ConfigurationManager class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) to store the settings.

Comment: seems your link directs me to amazon

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add it to settings file. In Visual Studio, go to My Project -> Settings and add it there. You can access it this way: C# - properties.settings.default...; VB - My.Settings...

Adding a setting to settings file stores the value in app config file and auto generates a class property for easy access to the value.